# Java float fails multiplication, addition when modifying position of object

Tags: java, jogl

Floats are not calculating as expected in my Java/JOGL (OpenGL for Java) program. In a draw method when each frame (at 60 frames per second) is called I try to modify the position of an object. All values are float values.

```
float timeElapsed=((float)(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastdrawn))/1000;
float moveZ=(timeElapsed*momentumZ);
System.out.println(moveZ);
this.transformation.z+=moveZ;
System.out.println(this.transformation.z);
```

Since `momentumZ` is initialized with 0.2f and this.transformation.z is initialized with 0.0f, the object should move on the z-axis. But my output is:

```
...
0.0024
2.58058064E8
0.0052
2.58058064E8
8.0000004E-4
2.58058064E8
0.001
2.58058064E8
```

So, moveZ has the right value but the addition messes it up. if I try to add a constant value such as 0.05f every frame, the object moves.

Where can this error be? Is there anything about floats I don't know?

Comment: Float addition surely works; the error must be somewhere else. Maybe something is happening in another thread?

Answer (score 4):

Note that:

```
2.58058064E8
```

is ~258 million. You are adding

```
0.0024
```

to that, not going to change anything...

If you are not familiar with this representation of a floating-point numbers, check the article here:

- http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-1996/jw-10-hood.html

Comment: yes, but the question is, if I init a value at 0 and only modify it by adding values like 0.0024, how does it rise to a value like 258 million

Comment: There are many factors (that depend on your other code) that can change that: first, what's `lastdrawn` on the start, then what is `this.transformation` - if it is a class, then is it possible there's some other method that changes `this.transformation.z`? I suggest you determine when is the first time it jumps from 0 to 2.5E8 and see what caused it.

Comment: So in different words, why does this.transformation.z+=moveZ increment it to 258 million but this.transformation.z+=0.0024f doesn't? I just changed that one line,the rest of the code is completely the same.

Comment: Because either something else changes `this.transformation.z` or your `moveZ` is not correct at some point (e.g. if you set `lastdrawn` to 0 at the beginning instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`) - try to see which of these it is.

Comment: The current Unix time of 1290259830 multiplied by your initial momentum of 0.2 is, quite unsurprisingly, 258 million!  It seems most certain that the problem is indeed lastDrawn starting at 0.

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is that you start with lastDrawn == 0 which will make up an extra-big number for moveZ in the first place.

Edit: You should dump *timeElapsed* to the Console, it should bring light into the dark.